# hidden buttons not inline when displaying them

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a html page on which I have a button that is called *new*.

```js
function handle_new() {
  document.getElementById('coki').style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById('btn_new1').style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById('btn_new2').style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById('btn_new2').style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById('btn_new4').style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
.inline {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <button class="button button3" id="btn_new" type="button" onclick="handle_new();">New</button>
</p>

<div class="inline" id="coki" style="display: none">
  <button class="inline" id="btn_new1" type="button" onclick="handle_new1();">New</button>
  <button class="inline" id="btn_new2" type="button" onclick="handle_new2();">New</button>
  <button class="inline" id="btn_new3" type="button" onclick="handle_new3();">New</button>
  <button class="inline" id="btn_new4" type="button" onclick="handle_new4();">New</button>
  <button class="inline" id="btn_new5" type="button" onclick="handle_new5();">New</button>
</div>
```

When somebody hits this button, 5 buttons show up (in coki div) but always under each other and not in the same row. The problem is that I included inline in the buttons and in the div tag too, but for some reason when I add display none, they always appear under each other and not next to each other.

Td tag and p tag instead of the div did not work either. What is the solution? Thanks

Comment: .in1line should be .inline in the CSS

Comment: @Gerard Thanks but the buttons are still under eachother for some reason...

Comment: the problem is that your applying the style directly on the html also when you set the `display: none` to the coki div the rest of its children (<button>) still have their display as `display:inline-block` use F12 if your on chrome to view the elements current properties.

Comment: @BobbyAxe When I hover over that element group I see div#coki.inline and all the buttons under eachother has the .inline ending. I can't understand

Comment: it means they all have the class of inline being applied to them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create instead a `display: none` class. 
Assign it to the desired element.
On button click simply remove that `none` className.
The element should return to it's initial state (inline-block)

```js
function handle_new() {
  document.getElementById('coki').classList.remove("none");
}
```

```css
.inline {
  display: inline-block;
}

.none {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <button class="button button3" id="btn_new" type="button" onclick="handle_new();">New</button>
</p>

<div class="inline none" id="coki">
  <button class="inline" id="btn_new1" type="button" onclick="handle_new1();">New</button>
  <button class="inline" id="btn_new2" type="button" onclick="handle_new2();">New</button>
  <button class="inline" id="btn_new3" type="button" onclick="handle_new3();">New</button>
  <button class="inline" id="btn_new4" type="button" onclick="handle_new4();">New</button>
  <button class="inline" id="btn_new5" type="button" onclick="handle_new5();">New</button>
</div>
```

P.S: by seeing your `handle_newNNN()` I'm afraid you're repeating lots of JS code... but that's another day's topic.

---

Humm, if I'm guessing right what you're up to - and that's to
**have a *Create New*** button that creates elements. And so forth. Here's how I'd do it:

```js
var btnNew = document.getElementById("btn_new");
var elCoki = document.getElementById("coki");
var itemsTot = 0; // Currently 0 items created. We'll increment on creation
var itemsMax = 5; // max number of new items

function newItem() {
  itemsTot += 1;
  var item = document.createElement('div');
  item.classList.add("item")
  item.innerHTML = "THIS IS ITEM n."+ itemsTot +" !";
  elCoki.appendChild(item);
  // Disable button
  if(itemsTot >= itemsMax) {
    btnNew.disabled = true;
    btnNew.classList.add("none");
  }
}

btnNew.addEventListener("click", newItem);
```

```css
.item {
  background: orange;
  padding: 4px; margin: 2px 0;
}
.none {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="coki"></div>
<button class="button button3" id="btn_new" type="button">+ New Item</button>
```

Comment: Thank you very much it works!!! Now, my last wish would be is not to show all the buttons, but hide one or two. For that reason I need to block them, how can I do it?

Comment: @DenisDore simply add `.none` to the desired buttons. `class="inline none"`

Comment: @DenisDore Hmm are you perhaps actually trying to: On some button click → dynamically create an element - up to 5 or 6 times?

Comment: the problem is that I always use python, now I have to create a webpage with some functions (graphs, adding new buttons, these stuff) and I'm forced to use javascript because Flask (python framework) is not enough when you have to stay on one page and implement functions on that single page. So I now started js, I'm getting  to know with it, so thanks for the help!

Comment: @DenisDore I used Flask. Yes, JS is a different beast ;) Happy coding

Comment: you are my hero, if you used flask, I'd have one last question: I've been suffering with this: I have to pass variables from javascript to flask, but till this time I did it with the usual method: form - post in js and request.form["name"] in flask. Do I need to use always posts, aren't there any other ways to pass variables to flask? Thanks for the 1000th time!

Comment: @DenisDore yes, Python is your back-end, just like PHP, to communicate you use  HTTP requests :) AJAX in this case helps in providing a better asynchronous user experience. That's the beauty, in creating say `@app.route("/someRoute", methods=["GET", "POST"])` where if the request type was `GET` you can render a page, whilst if `POST` you can handle your `request.form.get("someProp")` and after some Python logic is done you can return a JSON back to JS like (Python/Flask:) `return jsonify({"status":"ok", "message":"Welcome "+ session["username"]})`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I specify a little bit better: I have a variable in my example.html that I'd like to throw back to flask to deal with that variable. I'd like to do it without any forms, posting, requesting stuff, so like: render template("sadas.html", vari=variable) just backwards. As I read about it, when using ajax that variable should also get posted. My main goal is to reduce js code and let python do all the stuff (unfortunately, when implementing a new function on a single page this is not easy to solve as I experienced)

Comment: @DenisDore I'm afraid you'll have to do so. http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/patterns/jquery/ You can always wrap your JS/jQuery AJAX methods into custom helper functions... but jQuery is really so minimalistic that it's almost unnecessary. Google is your friend here.